# CSS Gradient Diagonal Striped Background Misalignment

Tags: css, sass

I have created a SCSS mixin based on the Bootstrap LESS mixin that will create a diagonally striped background. However, no matter how big I make the "tile" for the stripe, there always seems to be a 1px mis-alignment.  I'm guessing that it has something to do with sub-pixel calculations, but I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

http://codepen.io/allicarn/pen/ncHod

[image: Screenshot of codepen]

Here's a screenshot of the codepen (Chrome) with one repetition of the background highlighted.  Basically the 1px artifact originates from either edge not matching up to the next "tile"

Another goal would be to modify the angle and have it work, but that's just bonus points ;)

Comment: I learnt CSS Striping on [this arcticle](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/), that claims to have taken the idea from [Lea Verou site](http://lea.verou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/), and the code is the same of your. Well, both of them suffers of the same 1px misalignment problem (in the first example you have to enlarge the height and stop the animation to see it); I don't know if it's possible to get rid of the artifact, but if you will, remember to notify them and enjoy the epic win :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about support in older browsers, but an easier solution is

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, gray 0px, gray 25px, transparent 25px, transparent 50px, gray 50px);
```

Anyway, I can see still artifacts at pixel level

At least this way you get the bonus about working at any angle ...

Also, looking at the codepen **seems** solved by increasing the size of the body:

```
body {
    @include diagonalStripes(#aaa, 50px);
    height: 1000px;
}
```

[updated codepen](http://cdpn.io/yixul)

if this is the case, that would mean that the problem arises from the background extending beyond the element ?

Comment: Updated my answer, seems that I solved; but I am unsure about that working in others browsers

Answer (score 1):

Here's another type of LESS mixin for diagonal striped background:

```
.stripes(@angle: -45deg, @color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), @size: 4px /* size must be an even number */) {
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(@angle, @color, @color 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, @color 50%);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(@angle, @color, @color 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, @color 50%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(@angle, @color, @color 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, @color 50%);
  background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(@angle, @color, @color 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, @color 50%);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(@angle, @color, @color 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, @color 50%);

  .background-size(@size @size);
}
```

Hope it helps...